# IndexError in Python while splitting an input file based on a pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code tries to split the text data based on a separator but I keep getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "split.py", line 7, in <module>
    en_text = split_text[1].lstrip()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And the output of the two files has to be the same number of lines but I got `94132 en_out.txt` and `94304 mn_out.txt` for two of the files which im not sure what's going on.

The code I used is

```
with open('mn_en_sentences_split.txtaa') as inputFile:
    inFile = inputFile.readlines()

for i in inFile:
    split_text = i.split("+++++SEP+++++")
    mn_text = split_text[0].rstrip()
    en_text = split_text[1].lstrip()
    with open("mn_out.txt", "a") as mn_out:
        mn_out.write(mn_text + "\n")
    
    with open("en_out.txt", "a") as en_out:
        en_out.write(en_text)
```

The input file for this code can be found here at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GNo1XJxRFxjey5VDsHjLvj9upXJOqd3e/view

Comment: I'm not going to download the file to read it (stranger danger!), however to debug this further - I can suggest injecting some logging or print statements so you know *exactly* what the lists look like.

I would personally start at a quick `print(i)` and `print(split_text)` where you iterate on `inFile`.  Since that's where things are breaking down, you will want to see that your split is doing what you really think it is.

Comment: If `split_text[1]` is out of range, that means `split(separator)` returned a list of only one element, which means the separator text was not found in that line.

Comment: put 10 lines of the file in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the `IndexError` is that `split_text` only has 1 element when the line does not have the separator.

You have to deal with this case. Drop that line or choose a different processing.

Another case if the line has multiple separators. Marat had a nice solution for that case (see edit)

A few other refactor tips:

It is not needed to read the whole file before processing.

To get faster processing do not open and close files hundreds of times.

Use a debugger to inspect the results of the split if they contain the new line character.

If you don't need any white space at the ends of the string you can `strip()` them of all white space of only the new line char with `strip('\n')

And later add the new line for both written lines to keep them similar.

```
with open('mn_en_sentences_split.txtaa') as inputFile:
    with open("mn_out.txt", "w") as mn_out:
        with open("en_out.txt", "w") as en_out:
            for i in inputFile:
                split_text = map(lambda x:x.strip('\n'), i.split("+++++SEP+++++"))
                if len(split_text) < 2: continue  # drop line if no separator
                mn_out.write(split_text[0].rstrip() + "\n")
                en_out.write(split_text[1].lstrip() + "\n")
```

---

**Edit**

[Marat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271641/marat) made a few suggestions to refactor and fail safe the execution in case the separator is not found. The 3 `with` statements can be joined together with (syntax sugar) to reduce the indentation (not supported in all versions of Python 3.x).

I really like the variable unpacking of the split result. If it fails you get a `ValueError` exception.

I have chosen to skip the lines that do not have a separator. If you want to do something with these lines you have to put the `write()` calls outside/below the `try/except` and in the exception handler set `mn` and `en` to some value.

I like to keep the normal flow of code inside the try.

What and how you want to strip from the strings is all up to you depending on what you want and what the input might contain.

```
with open('mn_en_sentences_split.txtaa') as inputFile, \
     open("mn_out.txt", "w") as mn_out, \
     open("en_out.txt", "w") as en_out:
    for line in inputFile:
        try:
            mn, en = line.strip('\n').split("+++++SEP+++++", 1)
            mn_out.write(mn.rstrip() + "\n")
            en_out.write(en.lstrip() + "\n")
        except ValueError:
           pass
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem was, and how this code fixes it?

Comment: @JohnGordon I did not read the question accurate (late at night). I totally missed the `IndexError`